# Evaluate $ \int_{a}^{b}(A - f(x))dx$ where $A = [1/(b-a)] \cdot \int_a^b f(x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

My solution:

Using the definition of the integral, rewrite $f(x)$ in the expression $A = [1/(b-a)] \cdot \int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ as:

$$A = \frac1{b-a} \sum_{i = 0}^{n \to +\infty} f(x)\frac{b-a}n$$

The $b-a$ terms then cancel each other out resulting in:

$$A = \sum_{i = 0}^{n \to+\infty} \frac{f(x)}n $$ which is equal to $0$.

Therefore, the original expression $ \int_a^b (A - f(x)) \, dx$ simplifies to:

$$ -\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$$

I'm not sure if I've approached the problem correctly, and if my final expression should be rewritten in a simpler form (if possible).

Help or Confirmation?

Comment: If you use non-conventional notations like $$\sum_{i = 0}^{n \to +\infty},$$ you should say what it means and show how to  do calculations with it.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the integral of a function is a **real number**. Thus, we have
$$\int_a^bA\ dx=(b-a)A=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx$$
from which you should be able to get the solution.

Comment: Pretty much. I'd add the remark that the quantity $A$ as defined in the problem is the "average" value of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$, roughly speaking. That's why the integral of $A$ over $[a,b]$ is precisely the integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  What is
$$
\int_a^b A\,dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

$
\int_{a}^{b}(A - f(x))dx $ where $A = [1/(b-a)] \cdot \int_a^b f(x)\,dx
$

Therefore;

$A = [1/(b-a)] \cdot [g(b)-g(a)]$

Therefore;

$
\int_{a}^{b}([1/(b-a)] \cdot [g(b)-g(a)] - f(x))dx = [1/(b-a)] \cdot [g(b)-g(a)]\cdot (b-a) - [g(b)-g(a)]$

Therefore;

$
\int_{a}^{b}(A - f(x))dx = 0 $